# XDR post returning "access denied" in IE 8 & 9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, xss

I am making an ajax request from y.x.com to x.com, and I have everything working in most browsers except for IE 8 and 9, where I'm getting an Access Denied error. Here's my code

```
 if (!empty && radio_checked) {
        $(".modal-content").animate({
            height: "250px"
        }), 500, function () { };
        $.support.cors = true;
        var url = "localhost:5603/ajax/post/sell-exm/?" //localhost for testing locally


        if ($.browser.msie && window.XDomainRequest) {

            var xdr = new XDomainRequest();
            xdr.open("post", url+data); // *** ERROR HERE ***
            xdr.send(data); 

        } else {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: data,
                datatype: "jsonp",
                success: function(r){
                    //nothing needed here
                }
            });
        }
 }
```

Again, this works in all browsers except IE 8 & 9. Also I have an Access-Control-Allow-Origin custom header in place on web.config.

Comment: New development: I had fixed this yesterday by removing 'www' from the url, but last night another developer pushed a fix for something else and ended up breaking it. So here's what's going on now: I'm getting the same response with IE 8/9 as I am with other browsers, but it's not following the same logic in my Ajax Controller. I added a condition to return "here" (in my Ajax Controller) when the browser is IE 8/9, but now that sends back a 500 error.

Comment: Another realization I had is that I'm only getting this error on my local environment, but why? And why, if this error isn't blocking it on the live env, does it not follow the same logic as other browsers? Is it possible that I just can't see this error on the live environment in IE?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure if this is how XDR works, but it works like this on my server for some reason, but it looked like 'open' triggered the ajax response from my .Net back-end, and blocked the send from getting through (It doesn't sound right, but that's is how it looked in Fiddler). So no form data was being posted, which caused all the weirdness to happen.

To fix this, I changed the post to a get, and added a clause to my .Net Ajax Controller that said `if Request.Form.AllKeys.Length = 0`, get the query string instead.